# How do I color part of a graph under a line in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, area

I would like to have in the same figure a line plot and a part of the graph under the line colored (a confidence interval).

How can I do this in MATLAB?

I already tried the following, but it doesn't work (it only shows the area):

```
plot(theta, p_prior_cum)
area(theta(50:70), p_prior_cum(50:70))
axis([0  1  0  1])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use hold off and hold on to retain the current graph in the figure.

Like this:

```
hold on
plot(theta, p_prior_cum)
area(theta(50:70), p_prior_cum(50:70))
axis([0  1  0  1])
hold off
```

[Here is a link that describes the usage more thoroughly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html)